# Удаление объекта из json на php

Tags: php, json

Мне надо удалить объект из json. Например, у меня есть вот такая json-запись:
`{
"+79123456789":
{
"name":"name",
"date":"date",
"time":"time"
}`
Как реализовать на php удаление из нее объекта по ключу?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Важно чтобы json был валидный иначе он не распарсится.

```
$json = '{"+79123456789":{"name":"name","date":"date","time":"time"},"+333":{"name":"name","date":"date","time":"time"}}';
$arr = json_decode($json);
unset($arr->{"+79123456789"});
$newJson = json_encode($arr);
var_dump($newJson);
```

Результат:

```
string(52) "{"+333":{"name":"name","date":"date","time":"time"}}"
```